# In what order should I watch Sailor Moon series?

Tags: sailor-moon

I've been wanting to start watching *Sailor Moon* for a while now, but I never knew which is the first and last season.

Can someone tell me where to start and finish?

Comment: Do you mean what order the series go in? Because presumably the episodes of an individual series just go in order, unless there's some reason you think they don't.

Answer (score 7):

there are 2 Sailor Moon series. *Sailor Moon* and *Sailor Moon Crystal*, the latter being a [more faithful adaptation of the manga](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/26987/1587) but still different

> Sailor Moon Crystal is its own canon. It follows the manga more closely than does the classic anime, but also has points where it veered away from the manga content in ways that conflict with both manga canon and classic anime canon.

for episode lists you can look up Wikipedia and watch from the first episode

- [*Sailor Moon Crystal* Episode List](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Sailor_Moon_Crystal_episodes)
- [*Sailor Moon* Episode List](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Sailor_Moon_episodes)

currently *Sailor Moon* covers more of the plot as *Crystal* has only gotten up to the Death Buster Arc (Season 3 in the original anime).

Should also encourage that if you plan to watch *Sailor Moon* localized in english, don't watch the DIC Entertainment as this was edited from the original Japanese version where some episodes were dropped, plot points changed, they never did the Shadow Galactica series (the final season) and the biggest thing for me is that

> Haruka (Sailor Uranus) and Michiru (Sailor Neptune) where changed from being lovers to being cousins

Rather seek out [VIZ Media's](https://www.viz.com/sailor-moon) re-release which is more faithful to the original japanese anime with VIZ Media planning to release the final season (currently as of 03/05/2018 they are on the first half SuperS (Season 4))

Answer (score 1):

I have not actually watched the show to know the details of the chronology so I am going to make a couple of assumptions:

1. That you want to watch the whole series, including whatever Dic skipped.
2. That you want to watch each installment in the order they were originally shown in Japan.

First, before you begin watching the show, you may want to read the Codename Sailor V manga series for some background, since that was released first. Some of the events events are eventually touched upon in the Sailor Moon television series, but I do not remember when and they were technically published first so it gives you some insight on on Minako, Artemis and Sailor V.

As for the show itself, each season of the television series was published in this order:

- *Sailor Moon* (March 7th 1992–February 27, 1993 ) (46 episodes)
- *Sailor Moon R* (March 6th 1993–March 12th 1994) (43 episodes)
- *Sailor Moon S* (March 19th 1994–February 25th 1995) (38 episodes)
- *Sailor Moon SuperS* (March 4th 1995–March 2nd 1996) (39 episodes)
- *Sailor Moon Sailor Stars* (March 9th 1996–February 8th 1997) (34 episodes)

That order is enough if you just want to watch the actual show, but there were also three movies released in the middle of each season:

- *Pretty Soldier Sailor Moon R: The Movie* (December 5th 1993)
- *Pretty Soldier Sailor Moon S The Movie* (December 4th 1994)
- *Pretty Soldier Sailor Moon SuperS: The Nine Sailor Soldiers Unite! Miracle of the Black Dream Hole* (December 23rd 1995)

The episodes, [as titled by Viz on their region specific streaming website](https://www.viz.com/watch/streaming/sailor-moon), immediately preceding the release date of each movie were:

- 76 Magic of Darkness: Esmeraude's Invasion (December 4th, 1993)
- 116 Sunny Skies After a Storm: A Friendship Dedicated to Hotaru (dec 3rd, 1994)
- 157 Pegasus Disappears: Wavering Friendship (December 16th  1995)

However, episode 158 Pegasus's Secret: the Boy Who Protects the Dream World aired on the same date as the Super S Movie, and the titles suggest that it concludes a multipart episode. This in conjunction with the fact that without the aid of a V.C.R. it is harder to catch a new release of a television show, which only airs once at a certain time, than a movie which might run for a few days or a week suggests to me that people would have probably watched the television episode first. That is especially so since movies tend to be shown later than television shows.

From these datapoints I would assume you would want to watch it in this order

1. Watch all 46 episodes of the original Sailor Moon
2. Start Sailor Moon R: Watch 28 episodes of the season until overall series episode 76.
3. Watch the Sailor Moon R movie
4. Finish the remaining 17 episodes of Sailor Moon R until overall series episode 93
5. Start Sailor Moon S: Watch 23 episodes of the season until series overall episode 116
6. Watch The Sailor Moon S movie.
7. Finish the remaining 21 episodes Sailor Moon S until overall series episode 137
8. Start Sailor Moon Super S: watch 21 episodes of the season until overall series episode 158.
9. Watch the Sailor Moon SupersS movie
10. Finish the remaining 18 episodes of Sailor Moon S until episode 176.
11. Watch all 34 episodes of Sailor Moon Stars until the original series concludes with episode 200.

Then you are done.